# The algorithm used by the ode45 solver in matlab

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes

Does ode45 integrate first, then have functions of time t (antiderivatives), and then use the initial conditions, and then compute solutions for the time interval specified?  That's what we usually do analytically (by hand) with simple odes, so I'm wondering if ode45 follows these same steps.

Also, how long should I run ode45 for, before the solutions become garbage and untrustworthy, due to accumulations of numerical / round-off errors?  Is there a generally accepted max time, say, t_final = 30?

Comment: No, ode45 uses a numerical method. It uses the Runge-Kutta (4,5) formula.  Do you know Euler's method for numerically solving ODEs?  It's kind of like that.

Comment: Ode45 implements a Runge-Kutta type method called the Dormand-Price method. This does not use analytical solutions anywhere. As for numerical errors, it depends very sensitively on the problem. Some problems are "stiff" and will cause ode45 to develop large errors quickly; Matlab has other alternative solvers for these cases though they can also fail.

Comment: Usually you wouldn't want to do that, but some models have "events" in them. In these cases you might stop the solver upon an event, update your state (using the current state, presumably) and then restart with the updated state. One such event might be the creation or annihilation of a particle. I've done this recently, it's nicely supported in Matlab.

Comment: You just make another call to the solver with a different value of the state as the initial condition. If need be you can use the output variable to retrieve the previous value of the state to use to construct the new state.

Comment: Hi @Ian, I think I got it now!  Thanks so much! :)

Comment: The first part of this question is answered by the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#bu0200e-1) or by reading the actual code (type `edit ode45` in the Matlab Command Window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, `ode45` implements a numerical method of the Runge-Kutta family.

> Is there a generally accepted max time, say, `t_final = 30`?

There cannot be a simple number like that. Just by rescaling (replacing $t$ by $1000t$ in the equation) we can change whatever "the maximum time" was by the factor of 1000. The stability of solution greatly depends on the ODE itself (and its initial condition); for example the ODE $y'=y^2$ with $y(0)=y_0$ has exact solution $y(t) = y_0/(1-y_0t)$ which blows up at the time $t=y_0^{-1}$, at which point any numeric solution will cease to be meaningful.

> does stopping the ode45 solver, changing an initial condition, and then resume running the solver make any sense?

It doesn't help you gain accuracy. The algorithm `ode45` already controls the accuracy of the solution, using sophisticated (albeit necessarily heuristic) error estimates. (Roughly: if one computes the solution using a method of 4th order of accuracy, and then using a method of 5th order, then the difference of the results gives information about how far they are from the exact solution.) The algorithm adjusts the time steps as needed to maintain the accuracy.

Numerical packages, such as Matlab, allow the user to adjust the required tolerance for absolute or relative errors. See [Summary of ODE options](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/summary-of-ode-options.html); in particular, `odeget`  will display the options that are present by default.

Comment: I think that questions should be asked as questions, not as comments.